# Copy selection to a clipboard in tmux

Tags: tmux, clipboard

If I select text with a mouse in tmux in iTerm2 on macOS I get the selected text copied into my clipboard. I do not have to click any extra buttons - just select the text you want and you're done.

I've tested tmux in terminal.app on macOS but it doesn't work there - I have to hit `y` to copy the selection to my clipboard.

I thought that there is a mouse binding (something like `MouseOnSelection` similar to `MouseDown1Pane`) but I couldn't find anything useful on the web and `man tmux`.

I wonder if there is a way to have a similar behaviour on Ubuntu 16.10 - preferably in the Gnome terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tmux: Select and copy pane text with mouse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478922/tmux-select-and-copy-pane-text-with-mouse)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Tmux 2.4+ with vi copy mode bindings and [xclip](https://github.com/astrand/xclip):

```
set-option -g mouse on
set-option -s set-clipboard off
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -selection clipboard -i"
```

For older tmux versions, emacs copy mode bindings (the default), or non-X platforms (i.e., no xclip), see the explanation below.

---

Explanation: First we need to enable the mouse option so tmux will capture the mouse and let us bind mouse events:

```
set-option -g mouse on
```

Gnome-terminal doesn't support setting the clipboard using xterm escape sequences so we should ensure the `set-clipboard` option is off:

```
set-option -s set-clipboard off
```

This option might be supported and enabled by default on iTerm2 (see `set-clipboard` in the tmux manual), which would explain the behavior on there.

We can then bind the copy mode `MouseDragEnd1Pane` "key", i.e., when the first mouse button is released after clicking and dragging in a pane, to a tmux command which takes the current copy mode selection (made by the default binding for `MouseDrag1Pane`) and pipes it to a shell command. This tmux command was `copy-pipe` before tmux 2.4, and has since [changed](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/2.4/CHANGES#L6) to `send-keys -X copy-pipe[-and-cancel]`. As for the shell command, we simply need something which will set the contents of the system clipboard to whatever is piped to it; xclip is used to do this in the following commands. Some equivalent replacements for `"xclip -selection clipboard -i"` below on non-X platforms are [`"wl-copy"`](https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard) (Wayland), `"pbcopy"` (macOS), `"clip.exe"` (Windows, WSL), and `"cat /dev/clipboard"` (Cygwin, MinGW).

Tmux 2.4+:

```
# For vi copy mode bindings
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -selection clipboard -i"
# For emacs copy mode bindings
bind-key -T copy-mode MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -selection clipboard -i"
```

Tmux 2.2 to 2.4:

```
# For vi copy mode bindings
bind-key -t vi-copy MouseDragEnd1Pane copy-pipe "xclip -selection clipboard -i"
# For emacs copy mode bindings
bind-key -t emacs-copy MouseDragEnd1Pane copy-pipe "xclip -selection clipboard -i"
```

Before tmux 2.2:

Copy after mouse drag support was originally added in Tmux 1.3 through setting the new `mode-mouse` option to `on`. Tmux 2.1 changed the mouse support to the familiar mouse key bindings, but did not have `DragEnd` bindings, which were introduced in 2.2. Thus, before 2.2 I believe the only method of setting the system clipboard on mouse drag was through the built-in use of xterm escape sequences (the `set-clipboard` option). This means that it's necessary to update to at least tmux 2.2 to obtain the drag-and-copy behavior for terminals that don't support `set-clipboard`, such as GNOME Terminal.

Comment: This high quality answer is what finally made it all click for me.. thanks!

Comment: For anyone trying to do this on a mac because they've changed their terminal functionality and the default method as stated by the OP no longer works (I'm using Byobu which has its own copy buffer): replacing the `xclip...` statement with a simple `pbcopy` does the trick.

Comment: None of the solutions in this thread work for me.

Comment: Hi Josh, when I source-file ~/.tmux.conf, it turned out :`Unknown key: MouseDragEnd1Pane `

Comment: @XifengLi Which tmux version and OS are you using? I believe you need at least tmux 2.2 for the `DragEnd` keys.

Comment: this works. however, the selection contains a <RETURN> at the end, so when pasted, the terminal tries to execute the command, which can be annoying sometimes

Comment: worked on mint 20 for me after many other solutions ineffective including yank.tmux

Comment: The original answer uses ""xclip -se c -i", but note that very recent versions of xclip added the "-secure" flag (commit a21e11baba), so "-se" no longer is an abbreviation for "-selection".  It is better to spell out "-selection" as the parameter.

Comment: @eakst7 I'll update the answer; thanks for the information! I'm not sure why I abbreviated the selection flag in the first place, as I didn't do it in the full explanation.

Comment: As suggested by @DarrelHolt, I have to use `pbcopy` eg: 
`bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "pbcopy"`

Answer (score 40):

Yet another extension is about using `Shift` key.

Hold `Shift` while selecting text with mouse. Now you get a standard right-click menu (keep holding or press `Shift` again) and you can use `Ctrl+Shift+C` and `Ctrl+Shift+V` to copy and paste. Copied text will be also available in **system clipboard**.

Tested on `Ubuntu 18.04.1` with `tmux 2.6`.

Source: https://forum.upcase.com/t/tmux-ctrl-shift-c-and-ctrl-shift-v-bindings/1208.

Comment: This is the simplest and it works like a charm. Exactly what I've been missing.

Comment: For me as well this is the best solution

Comment: This saved me!!

Comment: this answer would be much cooler if it'd could work in remote / nested tmux sessions

Comment: This also solves the issue for me using Alacritty terminal on MacOS

Answer (score 13):

As an extension to the accepted answer, people often find that disturbing when releasing the mouse button exits the copy-mode (this is what happens with `copy-pipe-and-cancel`). See: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/140 .
Therefore, in newer tmux (I use 2.6) we can use `copy-pipe` together with `clear selection` to copy to selection but do not exit the copy-mode:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send -X copy-pipe "xclip -selection clipboard -i" \; send -X clear-selection
```

Answer (score 3):

Extending both answers to copy from msys2 to the Windows clipboard (and clear the selection):

```
# For vi copy mode bindings
bind -Tcopy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send -X copy-pipe "cat > /dev/clipboard" \; send -X clear-selection
# For emacs copy mode bindings
bind -Tcopy-mode MouseDragEnd1Pane send -X copy-pipe "cat > /dev/clipboard" \; send -X clear-selection
```

Comment: Good point. I use copy-mode myself (emacs style) and so had pasted my own config after testing. I've updated the answer to include both as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

to add to above answers, this works for me on mac. Using xclipboard does not work in my case.

```
bind -T copy-mode-vi  MouseDragEnd1Pane   send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel pbcopy
```